# gorilla mux router handlers

Tags: go, mux

I can not get the gorilla mux to work..

When requesting `http://www.localhost:9000` this is returned by the web server `404 page not found`

But this works `http://localhost:9000/` and prints `Hello world`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello world")
}

func main(){
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Host("www.localhost")
    r.HandleFunc("/", Handler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe error: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: /etc/hosts is set.. The webserver responds on `www.localhost` but with `404`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be able to support both localhost and www.localhost

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"

        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello world")
}

func main() {
        r := mux.NewRouter()
        r.Host("www.localhost").Path("/").HandlerFunc(Handler)
        r.HandleFunc("/", Handler)
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("ListenAndServe error: ", err)
        }
}
```

If you read the documentation carefully, you'll notice that r.Host() is just another pattern matching function. It doesn't set any global rule for that router.

if you want to make that rule to be inherited you'll need to use a subrouter:

```
subrouter := r.Host("www.localhost").Subrouter()
```

then you use "subrouter" in place of "r"